# how i can make fixed left column div?

Tags: wordpress

I have page:

`http://wordpress.metalabit.eu/`

How i can make fixed static left column?

I try make position fixed in css file:

`{display: block; position: fixed}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `#masthead` and `.sidebar-offcanvas` in a div (as a wrapper) with `position:fixed;`. Don't use `#secondary` because it's needed for the column width. Then obviously you need to define the breakpoint that the fixed position returns to inherit because otherwise your mobile nav is hidden.